# Opacity problem

Tags: css, transparency, opacity

When hovering an image, users can see some additional information about the image. Before it was transparent, but now I don't want it make it transparent. So I deleted the `opacity` line in my css. But then the block got a whole new look...

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

**CSS**

```
 #uicarousel-news-preview-block-1 .ui-carousel-item .views-field-title,
 #uicarousel-news-preview-block-2 .ui-carousel-item .views-field-title {
        height:35px;
        margin-top:-46px;
        background-color:green;
        padding-left : 30px;
        padding-right : 30px;
        opacity : 0.6;
        /*IE opacity*/
        filter:alpha(opacity=60);
        color: white;
        display: none;
    }
```

Is there something wrong with the CSS, or what do I have to do to make sure there is no opacity and the `div`is still in front of the image?

**UPDATE**
This is the HTML. It's a Drupal website and the green bar is the `views-field-title`
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
#uicarousel-news-preview-block-2 .ui-carousel-item .views-field-title
{
  ...
  position:relative; 
  /* z-index: ...; - if needed */
}
```

Comment: Great, did the trick!! Stupid of me not to think about it myself! Thanks